# How does PythonTeX work precisely "under the hood"?

Tags: auxiliary-files, pythontex

`PythonTeX` requires for correct typesetting code and its output at least 3 step compilation:

```
(lua/pdf/xe)latex
pythontex
(lua/pdf/xe)latex
```

On Windows 10, the first run creates (among others) file `\jobname.pytxcode`, `pythontex` run then creates (among others) files with `.stdout` extension, and third run reads content of these files and typesetts it.

Is that (at least remotely) correct? And how does it work precisely (on LaTeX, but also on Python side). I have been working with `PythonTeX` for some time, but I have found out that I am using it mostly as a "blackbox."

Motivation: I would like to create support for Haskell in `PythonTeX`. But Haskell has pretty specific IO and it would be very helpfull to me (and hopefully also for others) to know how `PythonTeX` precisely works.

Comment: There are existing approaches for running Haskell code and typesetting the results from within a LaTeX document, see for example http://daniel-diaz.github.io/projects/haskintex/.

Comment: I know about `HaTeX, haskintex`, also `haddock` can be used with `pandoc`. But I always look for tools that are actively developed and, excluding `haddock`, if I look at `haskintex`, it has last issue posted in 2017, without a reply.
Also, I need a solution that can be automated and used from tex-side (without batch-file) and on Windows. Tothese requirements, `pythontex` fits nicely.